# How to get data "value" data from HTML then save it to a variable?

Tags: html, excel, vba

I am attempting to get the data from a "value" then save toa variable for later use.

This is the code I'm looking at.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mfcv6.png)

I'm trying to get the jobOrder number of  "217703".  This changes for every file and there is no other way I've found to get this the JobOrder.

Comment: `var saveVal = document.getElementById('jobOrdersIds').value;`

Comment: Please include the code sample as *text*, not an image of it.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't shown any code. Are you using IE?

Something like:

```
Ie.document.getElementById("jobOrdersIds").value
```

Comment: Did you try this?